# Jenkins-HTTP proxy configuration-github plugin

Tags: proxy, github, jenkins

I am running a ubuntu Virtual Machine and through putty i am accessing it.I have installed jenkins CI on that machine.

Now i am in need to integrate the GitHub Plugin with that jenkins. That VM is behind the firewall, i need to install the plugin through HTTP Proxy configuration.

I have installed winproxy in my windows machine as a proxy server and i accessed Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->advanced(plugin installation) in my browser

server name:as my public IP
port:3128
username:WinProxy
password:my own password

(Do i need to give my windows username & password?)

But when i submit,Jenkins adds some random long password to it.

2)I have also downloaded github.hpi plugin to upload manually to that machine,that is also doesnt work.

So please someone help me how to integrate that plugin to that Vm which is running jenkins.

If i am wrong in any of the above steps,please rectify me.

Also not sure about the username & password of that winproxy,is it mandatory?

Please someone help me to solve this issue.